# Como resover error "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project Primerprograma" en Netbeans IDE 13

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin, java-17

estoy aprendiendo JAVA y probando el primer programa me ha salido el siguiente error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project Primerprograma: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

El código del programa es el siguiente:

```
package com.yadian.primerprograma;

/**
 *
 * @author yadia
 */
import java.util.*;
public class HolaFecha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola, hoy es: ");
        System.out.println(new Date() );
    }
}
```

El pom.xml es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yadian.holafecha</groupId>
    <artifactId>HolaFecha</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.yadian.holafecha.HolaFecha</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: podrias agregar tu pom.xml o una version reducida? para tener un [mcve]

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Acabo de agregar el pom.xml a mi pregunta original.

Comment: intenta cambiando `exec.mainClass` al valor `com.yadian.primerprograma.HolaFecha` en tu pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razon del error es que estas indicando la clase incorrecta. Contrario a lo que comunmente se cree para identificar una clase Java internamente usa el nombre de la clase e incluye el paquete y a esto se le denomina *fully qualified name*, o "nombre totalmente cualificado", y este se compone del paquete mas el nombre de la clase.

Tu especificaste

```
 <exec.mainClass>com.yadian.holafecha.HolaFecha</exec.mainClass>
```

Pero revisando tu codigo tienes

```
package com.yadian.primerprograma;

public class HolaFecha {
```

y por lo tanto tu nombre de tu clase principal deberia de ser

```
 <exec.mainClass>com.yadian.primerprograma.HolaFecha</exec.mainClass>
```